# html table border issue

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside some other HTML elements and it renders strange - the border space appears even if I set it in css as collapsed.
The table looks like this:

[image]

and the html is this:

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="1" class="scrollable-headers-only" title="" cellpading="0">
        <thead title="">
            <tr title="">
                <th class="check" title=""></th>
                <th class="type" title=""></th>
                <th class="name" title="">Name</th>
                <th class="address center-column" title="">Address</th>
                <th class="domain" title="">Domain</th>
                <th class="status" title="">Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

and the css, as it appears in FireBug is this:

- for the main table:
  [image]
- for each th:

[image]

I added border only too see the s[aces between cells. My issue is to eliminate that space. I added cellpading and cellspacing = 0 to the table, but doesn't make difference. I added css to eliminate that space, without any change in rendering.

This table is used as header for another table, and I need to align it's columns to the other one - as you can see from image, there are small lines under the table. I need to align this table with the second one, for this reason is important to get 100% precision.

What's wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Please post the actual CSS here, not just pictures of it.

Comment: A [JSFiddle replication](http://jsfiddle.net) or similar would be even better!

Comment: @j08691: the css is split in few files (and I use less.js to build it).

Comment: That's great, post the relevant parts here. And as James Donnelly mentioned, a jsFiddle example is helpful.

Comment: @ZelterAdy did you try `table td, table tr{padding: 0;}` ?

Comment: @j08691 the nice part is that in http://jsfiddle.net/ works. Something from the context - and I don't understand what - ass that space between the columns. For this reason I prefered to add screen shpts of the css as FF sees it. My hope is that someone will see something I mist on that css/html.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with removing `display: inline-block;` for `th` and `table` elements. Firefox treats those as inline elements and inserts extra space. Another way to eliminate it is to set `font-size: 0;` for `table` and in example `font-size: 12px;` for `th` element.

Comment: I already did that. And that doesn't help. The display : inline-block needs to be there.

Comment: @Zelter Ady
1) Why it has to be inline-block? It doesn't make any sens.
2) Then use the second solution - font-size: 0.

Comment: @Zelter Ady Here' working example: [working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AfzgB) - if you remove `font-size:0` for table, you'll see that `inline-block` is causing the trouble.